# Резиновый макет для модального окна

Tags: javascript, css

Делаю на JS модальные окошки (*jQuery и плагины не предлагать сразу*). для модального окна задан следующий CSS:

```
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
```

При помощи JS я добавляю нужный текст через innerHTML, после определяю размеры модального окна через (offsetWidth, offsetHeight) и делаю отрицательный margin-top, margin-left

```
win.style.marginTop = (-win.offsetHeight / 2) + 'px';
win.style.marginLeft = (-win.offsetWidth / 2) + 'px';
```

Когда текст, то все замечательно, но если вдруг я хочу отобразить **некэшированную** картинку, то offsetWidth и offsetHeight возвращают неверные данные (хотя в консоли хрома я вижу нужные мне размеры этих свойств). Как исправить такое?

Всем спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил свою проблему следующим образом:

```
var images = win.getElementsByTagName('img');
if (images) {
    var img = images[0];
    win.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    img.onload = function() {
        win.removeAttribute('style');
        win.style.marginLeft = (-win.offsetWidth / 2) + 'px';
        win.style.marginTop = (-win.offsetHeight / 2) + 'px';
    }
}
win.removeAttribute('style');
win.style.marginTop = (-win.offsetHeight / 2) + 'px';
win.style.marginLeft = (-win.offsetWidth / 2) + 'px';
```

Получилось дублирование кода, но думаю его здесь не избежать...

Comment: очень легко избежать, просто объявите функцию отдельно и вызывайте ее как

    img.onload=my_onload_function;

кроме того, чтобы проверить загружена картинка или нет, есть свойство complete (чтобы работало и в ie оно должно быть задано после присвоения src)